# Find the total values of a column from another table ?(using join or other functions)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables like this
Table 1

```
Group      ID         submit_date
1          153        2011-08-22
1          158        2011-12-02
1          245        2013-02-22
2          325        2014-01-20
2          285        2015-01-22
3          425        2016-04-22 
3          655        2017-02-22
```

Table 2

```
ID         as_date       amount
153        2011-09-01    500
153        2011-10-01    400
153        2011-11-15    350 
153        2012-01-25    250
153        2012-02-15    200
158        2012-01-02    10000
158        2013-05-02    8000
325        2014-02-20    5000
325        2014-03-20    4000
325        2014-04-20    3000
```

There are multiple records for each id of table 1 in table 2. I want to find total amount for each ID in table 1. Total amount due is equal to total amount of all ID from same group that submitted before current ID.  only should use amount due when the as_date is more recent and still less than submit date.

Example:

- ID 153: No ID submitted before then amount Due = 0
- ID 158 : ID 153 submitted before and 2011-11-15 is the most recent as_date that we have 350$ amount due (2011-11-15 is right before ID 158 submit date(2011-12-02))
- ID 245 : there are two ID in group 1 that have been submitted before this ID.
  The amount due should be 200+10000 :

  ```
  153        2012-02-15    200
  158        2012-01-02    10000
  ```

The as_of_date are before ID 245 submit date(2013-02-22)

Result

```
Group      ID         submit_date    Total_due_so_far
1          153        2011-08-22     0
1          158        2011-12-02     350
1          245        2013-02-22     10000+200
2          325        2014-01-20     0 (no ID submitted before for Group 2)
2          285        2015-01-22     3000
3          425        2016-04-22     0 (no ID submitted before for Group 3)
3          655        2017-02-22     0 (no ID submitted before for Group 3)
```

Comment: Are you using SQL-Server or MySQL? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166) (ignore if you're not asking about hw). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Search for other questions about calculating running totals in SQL.

Comment: SQL server or mysql does not matter. I just have problem how to get most recent as_date when I want to compare it with submit date. It is not HW too!

Comment: I said to ignore that part of the comment if it's not HW.

Comment: It may matter because you can use window functions in SQL-Server, but not MySQL. But if you just want to get the most recent `as_date` for each group, use `MAX(as_date)` and `GROUP BY group`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySql does not support analytical functions so far, so such a monster-query in plain SQL had to be created. It will not be very fast:

```
SELECT y.group, id, submit_date, coalesce( SUM( amt ), 0 ) As Total_due_so_far
FROM (
   SELECT x.group, id, submit_date,
          ( SELECT amount FROM table2 t2
            WHERE t2.id = id12
            AND t2.as_date <= x.submit_dateeee
            ORDER BY as_date DESC
            LIMIT 1
           ) As amt
    FROM (
      SELECT t11.group, t11.id as id, t11.submit_date, t12.id as id12,
             max( t2.as_date ) as submit_dateeee
      FROM table1 t11
      LEFT JOIN table1 t12
      ON t11.id <> t12.id AND t11.submit_date > t12.submit_date AND t11.group = t12.group
      LEFT JOIN table2 t2
      ON t2.id = t12.id AND t2.as_date < t11.submit_date
      GROUP BY t11.id, t11.submit_date, t12.id
   ) x
) y
GROUP BY y.group, id, submit_date
order by 1,2
;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e130e/38

```
| group |  id |          submit_date | Total_due_so_far |
|-------|-----|----------------------|------------------|
|     1 | 153 | 2011-08-22T00:00:00Z |                0 |
|     1 | 158 | 2011-12-02T00:00:00Z |              350 |
|     1 | 245 | 2013-02-22T00:00:00Z |            10200 |
|     2 | 285 | 2015-01-22T00:00:00Z |             3000 |
|     2 | 325 | 2014-01-20T00:00:00Z |                0 |
|     3 | 425 | 2016-04-22T00:00:00Z |                0 |
|     3 | 655 | 2017-02-22T00:00:00Z |                0 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `CTE's` you can retrieve the latest dates according to your specifications in a readable way.  In this example I am using `MS SQL Server`.

The query uses the `CTE` to get the most recent `as_date`. **Please note** that this example uses a `CROSS JOIN` so it is assumed that your tables are not extremely large.  Otherwise, this can be a huge performance hit.  The reasoning behind the `CROSS JOIN` is to get the combinations of the `ID's` to `ID's` and `as_date's`. From there you can the most recent one using

```
...
, MAX
        (
            CASE WHEN main.submit_date > t2.as_date 
                THEN t2.as_date 
                ELSE NULL
            END
        ) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.[group], t2.[ID] ) as recent_date
...
```

After that, `LEFT JOIN` back onto `table2` and `RIGHT JOIN` onto `table1` in order to get `ID's` with our without `NULL` values on the outer query and get the `SUM` for the amount.

**Example Data:**

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE ( [group] INT, ID INT, submit_date DATE )
DECLARE @table2 TABLE ( [ID] INT, as_date DATE, amount INT)

INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES 
( 1          , 153        , '2011-08-22')
,( 1          , 158        , '2011-12-02')
,( 1          , 245        , '2013-02-22')
,( 2          , 325        , '2014-01-20')
,( 2          , 285        , '2015-01-22')
,( 3          , 425        , '2016-04-22') 
,( 3          , 655        , '2017-02-22')

INSERT INTO @table2
VALUES
( 153        ,'2011-09-01'    , 500  ) 
,( 153        ,'2011-10-01'    , 400  )
,( 153        ,'2011-11-15'    , 350  )
,( 153        ,'2012-01-25'    , 250  )
,( 153        ,'2012-02-15'    , 200  )
,( 158        ,'2012-01-02'    , 10000)
,( 158        ,'2013-05-02'    , 8000 )
,( 325        ,'2014-02-20'    , 5000 )
,( 325        ,'2014-03-20'    , 4000 )
,( 325        ,'2014-04-20'    , 3000 )
```

**Solution Query**

```
;WITH Recent_As_Date_cte AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT main.[group]
        , main.[ID]
        , t1.ID AS [previous_id]
        , MAX
            (
                CASE WHEN main.submit_date > t2.as_date 
                    THEN t2.as_date 
                    ELSE NULL
                END
            ) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.[group], t2.[ID] ) as recent_date
    FROM @table1 t1 
        LEFT JOIN @table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
        CROSS JOIN @table1 main
    WHERE main.[group] = t1.[group]
        AND main.submit_date > t2.as_date
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.[group]
    , t1.[ID]
    , t1.[submit_date]
    , SUM( ISNULL(t2.amount, 0)) AS [Total_due_so_far]

FROM Recent_As_Date_cte c 
    LEFT JOIN @table2 t2 ON t2.as_date = c.recent_date
    RIGHT JOIN @table1 t1 ON c.ID = t1.ID
GROUP BY 
    t1.[group]
    , t1.[ID]
    , t1.[submit_date]
ORDER BY 
    t1.[group]
    , t1.[ID]
```